# How do I identify the right .php page

Tags: files

Trying to modify the template and translate some hard coded Strings on Drupal 7, I couldn't really easily find the architecture of a page. With the debug mode I can read in the code which .tpl is being used but nothing for the .php files.

Is there something like that in the documentation that I haven't yet found? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can get clue from .tpl file form view source page. The other option is to find the page callback of the the url. Each CiviCRM url defined in menu xml file has a callback. The page callback gives the clue which file is being invoked. For eg civicrm/activity/view

If you a grep 'civicrm/activity/view' on CRM/ and open the xml file you will see something like this

```
<item>
     <path>civicrm/activity/view</path>
     <title>View Activity</title>
     <page_callback>CRM_Activity_Form_ActivityView</page_callback>
     <access_arguments>access CiviCRM</access_arguments>
  </item>
```

Which means the file CRM/Activity/Form/ActivityView.php is called in this situation.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the tip Pradeep. We'll have look this way!